# Polynomial equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Given a variety $X$, [rational equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequate_equivalence_relation) gives an equivalence relation on $Z_i(X)$ leading to the Chow groups and used in the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem.

I was wondering about replacing $\mathbb{P}^1$ with $\mathbb{A}^1$ in this definition. This would be polynomial equivalence - equivalence via polynomial functions instead of equivalence via rational functions:

> Polynomial equivalence: $Z \sim_{pol} Z'$ if there is a cycle $V$ on $X \times \mathbb{A}^1$ flat over $\mathbb{A}^1$, such that $[V \cap  X \times \{0 \}]  − [V \cap X \times \{ 1 \} ]  = [Z] − [Z' ]$.

Is it possible to make sense of $[ ]$ above, and if so does this give an adequate equivalence relation?

Comment: There is no difference between the two relations. Let me call R! the usual one and R2 the one you define. By an automorphism of the projective line, $\infty, 1$ are equivalent and so R1 implies R2. Conversely, take the closure of $V$ in $X\times\mathbb{P}^1$ to see that R2 implies R1.

Comment: Thanks. Could you leave this as an answer, maybe with a few more steps added on the second part? I would gladly accept it. @Mohan